# EaselJS show portion of an image

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am trying to display a progressbar using EaselJS.
My progressbar background-image is 200px, and fully displaying that would mean the progress is at 100%.
How can I show only draw a percentage of an image in EaselJS? And is it possible to animate/tween towards more %?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `mask`: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_mask

Here is an example on how a mask could be used: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/Masks.html